# Ошибка прогнозирования python

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, flask, машинное-обучение

Я хочу получить правильный результат прогнозирования. Прогноз основан на 5 инпутах и 5 значениях. По одному значению в каждом. Мне нужно сделать всего один инпут, чтобы в него поместить 5 значений. Я использовал библиотеку `select2`, но прогноз был неверный. Я думаю, что это из-за этой библиотеки, т.к видимо на выходе функция прогнозирования получила только одно значение, а остальные 4 просто пропустила.Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы был один инпут и все 5 значений в нем считывались?

Код:

`app.py:`

```
app = Flask(__name__)

with open('templates/Testing.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        values = next(reader)
        values = values[:len(values)-1]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def dropdown():
        return render_template('includes/default.html', values=values)

@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    selected_values = []
    if(request.form['Value1']!="") and (request.form['Value1'] not in selected_values):
        selected_values.append(request.form['Value1'])
    if(request.form['Value2']!="") and (request.form['Value2'] not in selected_values):
        selected_values.append(request.form['Value2'])
    if(request.form['Value3']!="") and (request.form['Value3'] not in selected_values):
        selected_values.append(request.form['Value3'])
    if(request.form['Value4']!="") and (request.form['Value4'] not in selected_values):
        selected_values.append(request.form['Value4'])
    if(request.form['Value5']!="") and (request.form['Value5'] not in selected_values):
        selected_values.append(request.form['Value6'])

    result = prediction.dosomething(selected_values)
    return render_template('predict.html',result=result, values=values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`default.html:`

```
<div id="Value" class="tabcontent">
  <form name="ValueForm" id="ValForm" method="POST" action=/predict>
    <div class="head">
      Select your values
    </div><br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <!-- <select multiple data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control" size=1>
          {% for val in values %}
          <option value= "{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select> -->
      <label for="Value1" align="left">Value 1</label>
      <input type="text" list="values" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="Value1">
      <datalist id="val">
          {% for val in values %}
          <option value= "{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </datalist>

      <label for="Value2" align="left">Value 2</label>
      <input type="text" list="values" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="Value2">
      <datalist id="val">
          {% for val in values %}
          <option value= "{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </datalist>

      <label for="Value3" align="left">Value 3</label>
      <input type="text" list="values" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="Value3">
      <datalist id="val">
          {% for val in values %}
          <option value= "{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </datalist>

      <label for="Value4" align="left">Value 4</label>
      <input type="text" list="values" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="Value4">
      <datalist id="val">
          {% for val in values %}
          <option value= "{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </datalist>

      <label for="Value5" align="left">Value 5</label>
      <input type="text" list="values" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="Value5">
      <datalist id="val">
          {% for val in values %}
          <option value= "{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </datalist>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 10px;" name=form>Identify</button>
</form>
```

`predict.py:`

```
data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join("templates", "Training.csv"))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
cols = df.columns
cols = cols[:-1]
x = df[cols]
y = df['prognosis']
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

print ("DecisionTree")
dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf_dt=dt.fit(x_train,y_train)

indices = [i for i in range(137)]
values = df.columns.values[:-1]

dictionary = dict(zip(values,indices))

def dosomething(value):
    user_input_values = value
    user_input_label = [0 for i in range(137)]
    for i in user_input_values:
        idx = dictionary[i]
        user_input_label[idx] = 1

    user_input_label = np.array(user_input_label)
    user_input_label = user_input_label.reshape((-1,1)).transpose()
    return(dt.predict(user_input_label))
```

`identify.html:`

```
{% block body%} 
    <p><b>{{ result[0] }}</b></p> 
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Если вас интересует прогноз, то причем тут select2? Удалите из кода все лишнее, весь ввод и весь вывод. Оставьте только  сами УЖЕ ВВЕДЕННЫЕ данные и результаты прогноза. Как минимум, станет понятно - у вас ошибка прогноза или ошибка ввода-вывода. Тогда можно будет о чем-то говорить.

Comment: @passant он нужен для того, чтобы получать несколько значений в одно поле input

Comment: Вы так и не поняли о чем я написал.  Хотите разгребать вашу кашу - дело ваше. Хотите локализовать ошибку - можете последовать моему совету. Если вы уверены что дело во вводе, то причем тут "прогнозирование" и "машинное обучение"? Меняйте теги, придут те, что занимается front-end. А "прогнозирование" - это совсем другие люди.

Comment: @passant я думал, чем больше подробного кода, тем лучше. Подскажите, что убрать конкретно.

Comment: Я же написал выше. Если вы УВЕРЕНЫ, что проблема в инпутах -  удалите все, что к ним не относиться, измените теги. Придут специалисты по front-end. Если вы  УВЕРЕНЫ, что ошибка именно в процедуре прогнозирования, то тогда все равно, как вы данные получайте -  оставьте только процедуру прогнозирования и покажите на конкретных данных, как "не так" она работает. Если вы НЕ УВЕРЕНЫ ни в том ни в другом  - сперва локализуйте ошибку. А потом действуйте по описанной выше схеме. Это же совершенно тривиальный способ отладки - декомпозиция и локализация ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

исходя из уточняющих вопросов в ЛС:

требуется одна форма в которой можно сделать мультивыбор без ctrl/shift -

`test.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <section>
        <div class="container h-100">
            <form action="/home" method="POST" class="form-inline">
                <select id='sel' name='sel' class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true">
                    {% for val in values %}
                    <option value= "{{val}}">{{val}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Select</button>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $('select').selectpicker();
            </script>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

всё это передать в python и вызвать `dosomething()`, которая принимает список, из `predict.py` -

`test.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def login():
    values = [1, 2, 3]
    return render_template('test.html', values=values)


@app.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    print(request.form.getlist('sel'))
    return 'OK', 200


app.run(host='10.10.10.2', port=5555, debug=True)
```